# How can I remove a specified node from a linked list?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I've made a remove method that removes an object from a singly linked list.

So far the method removes the first node and the second node without a problem. When removing the third node and onward the method removes everything between the specified node and the head node. My question is how can I make my method remove the specified node and not everything before it?

I know I need to keep a reference to the previous node in order to assign its next node to the specified nodes next node. This will close the gap and remove the node. I understand the logic but can't seem to implement it.

```
public class List_test{
    public Node head;
    public List(){
        head = null;
    }
    public List(Node head_) {
        this.head = head_;
        Node ref = head;
    }
    public void remove(Node node) {
        Node ref= head;
        if (ref.equals(node)) {
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }
        while (ref != null) {
            if (ref.equals(node)) {
                head.next = node.next;
            }
            ref = ref.next;
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new List_test();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing a node, why are you changing the head pointer? You should be using the previous node and point it to the next node of the node to be removed.

Comment: I understand but how can I reference the previous node?

Comment: You will have to have a variable to hold that. For example before your while loop starts, previousNode = null as the ref is pointing to head and there is no previous node. In the loop when you do <br> `ref = ref.next` set previousNode to ref that way you have the previous nodes for each node traversed

Answer (score 1):

I think this page have nice explanation for this topic:
[deleting node in linked list c/c++, java, python](http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/)